# Python gambling dice game?

Tags: python, python-3.8, dice

I am new to lerning Python and am struggling with creating this dice roll gambling game. I have spent a good week on it, and am still just frustrated with not being able to get it to work properly/fully. Basically I am having a hard tim egetting it to print properly and continue to ask for the user's dice roll guess (between 2 to 12).
I thank anyone in advance for their help and suggestions!

Comment: You could put it all into a loop and [`break` (keyword to escape loops)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) on the exit conditions!

Comment: You forgot a few 'f''s in front of your strings that use variables.

Answer (score 1):

You're `total_bank()` method may be causing the trouble.

```
def total_bank():
    bank = 500
    while bank > 0:
        print("You have ${bank} in your bank.")
        bet = int(input("Enter your bet: "))
```

When you call this function, it'll tell you how much money you have in your bank, and once you enter in your bet, it'll do it again because bank is still >0. So, you'll just be stuck in this infinite loop.

ALSO, you'll need a lot of `global` keywords in this case. Although it is [not advised to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil), I think it's fine in this case. You're not actually changing the bank amount - that `bank` variable is a local variable, meaning you can't access it outside the `total_bank` function. You'll have to return `bank` every time you call it.

So, the code should be

```
def total_bank():
    bank = 500
    print(f"You have ${bank} in your bank.")
# you forgot to make in a f-string
    bet = int(input("Enter your bet: "))
    bank-=bet
    return bank
```

However, it may not be right for what your purposes are. For example, you can look limit the bet, etc. I'm just simplifying it.

Something like this is what you REALLY might want, but I'm not sure.

```
def total_bank():
    bank = 500
    print(f"You have ${bank} in your bank.")
# you forgot to make in a f-string
    while bet <= 500: #whatever number is fine
        bet = int(input("Enter your bet: "))
    return bank, bet

bank, bet = total_bank()
```

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

If you make some changes to the `total_bank` function and the main loop, you will get the results you want.

Try this code:

```
import random

def rollDice():
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)
    x = int(die1 + die2)
    print('Roll', x)
    return x

def prog_info():
    print("My Dice Game .v02")
    print("You have three rolls of the dice to match a number you select.")
    print("Good Luck!!")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print(f'You will win 2 times your wager if you guess on the 1st roll.')
    print(f'You will win 1 1/2 times your wager if you guess on the 2nd roll.')
    print(f'You can win your wager if you guess on the 3rd roll.')
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")

def total_bank(bank):
    bet = 0
    while bet <= 0 or bet > min([500,bank]):
        print(f"You have ${bank} in your bank.")
        a = input("Enter your bet (or Q to quit): ")
        if a == 'q': exit()
        bet = int(a)
    return bank,bet

def get_guess():
    guess = 0
    while (guess < 2 or guess > 12):
        try:
            guess = int(input("Choose a number between 2 and 12: "))
        except ValueError:
            guess = 0
        return guess

prog_info()
bank = 500

while True:
    bank,bet = total_bank(bank)
    guess = get_guess()

    if guess == rollDice():
        bank += bet
    elif guess == rollDice():
        bank += bet * .5
    elif guess == rollDice():
        bank = bank
    else:
        bank = bank - bet

    print(f'You have ${bank} in your bank.')
    print(f'Thanks for playing!\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

**'F' Strings**

F-strings replace whatever is in the squiggly brackets {} with the value of an expression such as a return value from a function or just any variable/value:

```
print(f"abc{1+2}") # output: abc3
```

In your **prog_info** function, your print statements don't actually need F-Strings however, lines such as these need to use F-Strings since you need to substitute values in:

```
print("You have ${bank} in your bank.")
print('Die Roll #1 was {roll}')
```

**Game Loop**

You could implement a while True loop with and if statement inside to exit if any of your conditions are not met

```
bank = 500 # Initial Amount    

while True:
    # Ask user for their bet/guess
    print(f'You have ${bank} in your account')
    print(f'Choose a number between 2-12')
    guess = get_guess()
    if guess == 0:
        break  # This stops the loop
    
     # Roll Dice, Add/Subtract from their bank account, etc.
    
     # Check if their bank account is above 0 after potentially subtracting from their account
     if bank <= 0:
         break
else:
     print("Thanks for playing")  # Game has ended
```